# How can i see a list of developers I have allowed for apps on my Mac (Mojave)

Tags: macos, mojave, gatekeeper

I have recently used "system preferences, security & privacy, general" to allow an app downloaded from an identified developer.

However, I was a bit quick and don't believe the developer name (which I have forgotten) corresponded to that on the app in question.

How can I see a list of developers that I have allowed and "un-allow" one of them, if necessary,?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Techinically approving an app from an developer is known as adding a "GateKeeper exception". However this is not done based upon the actual name of the developer (such as "Mega Super Software Ltd.") but rather based on certificates and so called code directory hashes.

You can use the Terminal to review the list of GateKeeoer exceptions you've added with a command like this:

```
sudo spctl --list --type execute
```

And you can remove a program from the list of exceptions by running a command like this:

```
sudo spctl --remove /Applications/AnApplication.app
```

where AnApplication.app is the app you want to no longer have approved.

As you can see the list of exceptions is hard to read as it doesn't include company or personal names, but rather these hash values and references to certificates.

Usually you'll see certificate rules being based on "anchor apple" (which means that the certificate chain of the app starts with Apple's own certificate) and that specific fields such as 6.2.6 and 6.1.13 are present, which means that it should be an Apple Developer certificate. Sometimes you'll also see that the leaf certificate (the last certificate in the chain) needs to have a specification OU (organizational unit) - for example WYH8F23PA3 or similar. This is Apple's internal code number given to organizations that have developer accounts.

The rules that are given using code directory hashes looks like 'cdhash H"1b9a8384...."' or similar. A code directory hash is a 256-bit number that can be calculated from the contents of the app, is almost guaranteed unique for a specific app and which ensures that if the app code is altered (for example to introduce malicious code) then the code directory hash will no longer match the app.

There's no publically available central storage of which actual company names / personal names corresponds with which cdhashes or certificate values. However you can inspect the files on your system to lookup the values for them.

You can inspect an application and find the above mentioned values, by running this command in the Terminal:

```
codesign -d -r- -vvvv /Applications/AnApplication.app
```

It will output a lot of information, amongst these the cdhash as well as certificate information and the actual company or personal name of the developer ID.

Note that if you haven't got the actual application anymore, you cannot easily find its cdhash or certificate information. Therefore you can have exception rules stored in GateKeeper for which you cannot find a matching cdhash or certificate.

Comment: I tried your command, but it's not really useful output. There's no names of applications or developers, just hash values.

Comment: Unfortunately the developer names are not stored In the system, so you cannot list them. Instead the values identifying the certificates are listed. If you still have the application binary, you could get the developer name from there - otherwise it’s not available. There’s also no online list or database where you can look it up unfortunately.

Comment: So what use is this list for the OP?

Comment: This is how you see what you have allowed and unallow one of them. I’ll revisit this and expand on the answer to make that even clearer.

Comment: Looking at the _manual page_ for `spctl` in the **SYNOPSIS** section, I believe it shows when using one of the following _options_ `--enable | --disable | --remove` and is using the _path_ to an _application_ you'd also use  `[--path path]` so `sudo spctl --remove /Applications/AnApplication.app` should be `sudo spctl --remove --path /Applications/AnApplication.app`. That said, testing under **macOS High Sierra**, neither removed the target _application_ from the _database_. Any suggestions?